# SQlite Select all when filter has a specific value

Tags: python, sqlite

```
cur.execute(""" SELECT %s FROM TVShowData WHERE julianday(_Starttime) + (_RunningTime / 24.0 / 60.0) > julianday('now', 'localtime') AND WatchType = '%s' ORDER BY StartTime LIMIT 15""" % (','.join(properties), category))
```

what "wildcard" for category I have to use, that I get all

category could have 3 different values that match with WatchType and I would need one that match with all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put parentheses around the comparison:

```sql
... WHERE ... AND (WatchType = '%s') ORDER BY ...
```

then you can use the value `' OR '' = '` to deactivate the comparison.

However, constructing the SQL query so that it is vulnerable to SQL injection is a bad idea; you should use parameters instead.
To deactivate the `WatchType` comparison, just leave it out:

```
query = """SELECT %s
           FROM TVShowData
           WHERE julianday(_Starttime) + (_RunningTime / 24.0 / 60.0) > julianday('now', 'localtime')
           %s
           ORDER BY StartTime
           LIMIT 15"""
if category:
    filter = " AND WatchType = ?"
    parameters = (category,)
else:
    filter = ""
    parameters = ()
query = query % (','.join(properties), filter)
cur.execute(query, parameters)
```